# Magento access magento session from outside same domain

Tags: session

I need to access magento session from outside but same domain.

domain: example.com

I need to access from: example.com/test

I used this code. But its not giving correct output even I logged to magento.

```
        require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/app/Mage.php");
        Mage::app(); 
        define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));
        $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
            $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);
        $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
        $customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();
        $telefono = $customer->getTelefonoMovil();
        var_dump($customer);
```

Comment: You want to load customer outside magento ?

Comment: @PrashantBarot Not exactly. I want to find whether customer is logged to magento. And if its so I need to log him to forum I built seperately

Comment: Please check below answer and tell if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this below code

<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php'; umask(0); Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) 
{    $customer =
  Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sessionCustomer->getId()); 
  echo $customer->getEmail(); 
} 
else 
{    
  echo "Not Logged"; 
}     
?>
```

Comment: This is working in external php file. But for forum I use codeigniter php framework. So when I do this inside codeigniter controller its gives "Not Logged"

Comment: can you try outside codeigniter set seesion and use that in inside codeigniter as i am not familiar with codeigniter

Comment: Its still not displays that session variable